# How to enable power management on startup in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I accidentally removed the power management program in the System > Preferences > **Startup Applications** panel and ever since I have had to go to System > Preferences  and then run **Power Management** just to see my battery life remaining.

How do I turn this feature back on at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already able to solve this by going to System > Preferences > Startup Applications. I clicked on Add and then placed this command into the command field:

> gnome-power-manager --verbose --no-daemon

Answer (score 2):

I have Ubuntu 10.04 in VirtualBox. If I have the address correct this should work.

You can click on:

System > Preferences > Startup Applications -> in the "Startup Programs" tab click on the "Add" button, then browse to the "File System" folder (/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-power-management.desktop), and click "Open" (this will enter the address in the Command Address space).

[image: Startup Applications Preferences Snip]

Type "Power Manager" in the "Name" space and then click on the "Add" button. This should return Power Management  to  the Startup Applications Preferences. If you have removed it totally, you may have to use a live cd to load from.

If that does not work, a less than desirable way is to click on the "Options" tab in "Startup Applications Preferences." Having only the minimum apps running  including "Power Management" and click on 'Remember Currently Running  Applications' or 'Automatically Remember Running Applications when logging out',  the application should run the next time you logon.

1. In the Terminal, enter "gconf-editor," click "enter," then in the left pane, expand apps, scroll down and expand gnome-power-manager and click notify. A list of possible notifications will appear in the right pane. Clicking on the options will bring up a description in the lower right part of the screen. Also check /schemas/apps/gnome-power-manager/notify (same editor).
2. You can open "Power Management," click on the 'General' tab, then click on 'always show icon' if that has failed.
3. You can right-click on Power Management" and then 'add this launcher to panel' this at least will place it on the panel.

   Or from this link you can check if the battery status is available for Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10 via the following PPA:

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status` and `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install battery-status`

   The applet will, initially, run as a standard gnome applet. To initiate 'indicator applet' mode, you will need to run the following command in a terminal:

   ```
   /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator
   ```

This information came from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets/) and more information [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/). Step 1's information came from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1050875).

Comment: I tried everything except the live cd option. None of them worked. I still have to manually run power management to see the battery remaining indicator. Thanks for the leads though :)

Comment: @Jeune-I have added some other options - from 1). to 'hope this helps'

Comment: Ok I'll try this out today. Will get back to you.

Comment: @Jeune, sorry found another poss, have placed it in as '1)'

Comment: Nope #1 didn't work. I am pretty sure installing Battery Status will solve my problem but that's not what I want for now. Most of your suggestions have to do with putting back the icon but I think the problem is, the power management process is not starting during startup. I know because before when I unplugged my laptop, the light becomes dim. Now I have to turn on power management manually just so the light will become dim.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far though ;)